# Scattered x,y,z via python's matplotlib.pyplot.contourf

Tags: python, matplotlib

Most pyplot examples out there use linear data, but what if data is scattered?
`x = 3,7,9

     y = 1,4,5

     z = 20,3,7`

better meshgrid for contourf
`xi = np.linspace(min(x)-1, max(x)+1, 9)

 yi = np.linspace(min(y)-1, max(y)+1, 9)

 X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)`

Now "z" data got to be interpolated onto the meshgrid.
`numpy.interp` does little help here, while both *linear* and *nn* interpolaton of
`zi = matplotlib.mlab.griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi,interp="linear")`
returns rather strange results

`scipy.interpolate.griddata` *cubic* from second answer below needs something else to return data rather than nils

With custom levels data expected be looking something [like this](http://www.emhi.ee/ilma_andmed/input/tuleoht/tuleohukaart.gif)

Comment: Question is how to display this data (grid+data) via contourf (filled colors via custom levels, no contours), and later apply to mpl_toolkits' Basemap with shapefile, but that's another step.

Comment: Whats the bit your stuck on? You just need to use `masked arrays` as I describe below. If you want filled contours just add `CS2 = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 20)`.

Comment: Before we do masking we need z interpolated over zi, right? Data
`x = 3,7,9  
y = 1,4,5  
z = 20,3,7`
grids:
`xi = np.linspace(min(x)-1, max(x)+1, 9)
yi = np.linspace(min(y)-1, max(y)+1, 9)  
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)`

Time for "z" >> zi _meshgrid numpy.interp_ is useless,
"linear" and "nn" of _matplotlib.mlab.griddata_ returns rather strange results.
_`zi = matplotlib.mlab.griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi,interp="linear")_

scipy.interpolate.griddata_ "cubic" from second answer below needs something else to return data rather than nils

Answer (score 2):

`countourf` will only work with a grid of data. If you're data is scattered, then you'll need to create an interpolated grid matching your data, like this: (note you'll need scipy to perform the interpolation)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from numpy.random import uniform, seed

# your data
x = [3,7,9]
y = [1,4,5]
z = [20,3,7]

# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(0,10,300)
yi = np.linspace(0,6,300)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata((x, y), z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
# contour the gridded data, plotting dots at the randomly spaced data points.
CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar() # draw colorbar
# plot data points.
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o',c='b',s=5)
plt.xlim(min(x),max(x))
plt.ylim(min(y),max(y))
plt.title('griddata test (%d points)' % len(x))
plt.show()
```

See [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data) for the origin of that code.

Comment: Let's check what **numpy.interp** and even more straight for the case **matplotlib.mlab.griddata** can do here..

Comment: Even with fixed xi/yi ranges zi is full of "nan" and contour shows nothing

Comment: Works for me, after fixing the range of the arrays. `xi = np.linspace(0,10,300); yi = np.linspace(0,6,300)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens:
[image]

Although `contour` requires grid data, we can caste scatter data to a grid and then using `masked arrays` mask out the blank regions. I simulate this in the code below, by creating a random array, then using this to mask a test dataset (shown at bottom). The bulk of the code is taken from [this matplotlib demo page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour).

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

from numpy.random import *
import numpy.ma as ma

J = random_sample(X.shape)
mask = J > 0.7
X = ma.masked_array(X, mask=mask)
Y = ma.masked_array(Y, mask=mask)
Z = ma.masked_array(Z, mask=mask)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 20)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
plt.savefig('cat.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]